# Programmatically change all reports

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function that logs when users run a report.  It is set to run "on open".  Is there a way to change the on open for all reports and forms at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code loops through all forms:

```
Public Sub DoChangeModules()
    Dim dstApp As Application
    Dim dstDB As Database
    Dim AO As Document

    Set dstApp = Application
    Set dstDB = dstApp.CurrentDb

    ' iterate forms's modules and insert code
    Dim f As Form
    Dim M As Module
    Debug.Print "Modifying Modules:"
    Debug.Print "Forms:"
    For Each AO In dstDB.Containers("Forms").Documents
        dstApp.DoCmd.OpenForm AO.Name, acViewDesign
        Set f = dstApp.Forms(AO.Name)
        Set M = f.Module
        ProccessModule M
        Set f = Nothing
        dstApp.DoCmd.Close acForm, AO.Name, acSaveYes
    Next AO
    
End Sub

Public Sub ProccessModule(M As Module)
    Dim numLine As Long
    Dim StartLine As Long, StartColumn As Long, EndLine As Long,     EndColumn As Long

    Debug.Print , , M.Name

    ' insert variable declaration
    M.AddFromString "Private testVar As variant ' test addition of module-level variable"

    ' locate or create Load event procedure
    StartLine = 0
    StartColumn = 0
    EndLine = 0
    EndColumn = 0
    If Not M.Find(" Form_Open(", StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine,    EndColumn) Then
        numLine = M.CreateEventProc("Open", "Form")
    End If



    numLine = M.ProcBodyLine("Form_Open", 0) ' 0 here is vbext_pk_Proc
    M.InsertLines numLine + 1, "" & _
                           "    ' Call of global function that logs user" & vbNewLine & _
                           "    doLogUser testVar " & vbNewLine & _
                           "    ' that function called with local module variable "


End Sub
```